# [aspnetboilerplate]How to specify specific feature for Organization Unit

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

In the existing Feature and Permission system, Abp caters for specifying a Feature level for a Tenant.  Under the Tenant Feature level one could add the permission for a User based on the available Tenant Feature.

But what I am trying to achieve is a sub-feature for an Organization unit.

So for example, I set "Product" and "Book" feature for one tenant, and this tenant only want to assign "Product" to one Organization Unit, how would I go about implementing a FeatureProvider to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Related issue: [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#3419](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3419)

Comment: This is also my post, and I want to check whether there is any built-in implementation.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: as there's no built-in this function, you need to extend the feature system.